# Java unable to execute CMD commands in java

Tags: java

I have a problem. I am trying to execute the following command in java:

```
cd C:\Users\Alexander\Projects/Simulator && mvn package
```

In the CMD command line, this command does get executed correctly, but when I try to run it in java using the following code:

```
try {
    String compileSimulatorCommand = "cd C:/Users/Alexander/Projects/Simulator && mvn package";
    Process compileSimulatorProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(compileSimulatorCommand);
    compileSimulatorProcess.waitFor();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this returns in the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1142)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:415)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:312)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:483)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1109)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `cd` does not exist outside the command prompt, and you're not using the command prompt in your code.

Comment: The string literal has unescaped `\`s and does not compile. (Also you seem to be trying for a shell command rather than executing an executable. So you should use the executable `cmd`, `sh` or similar depending upon platform.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline sorry for the not compilable string, I am building the string using variables, but I copy/pasted it wrong. I have edited the string to how it should work. I need to run this program on linux and windows. How can I use the command prompt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run `cd` as a command. You can instead set the working directory when you `exec` your command.

```
Process compileSimulatorProcess = Runtime
    .getRuntime()
    .exec(
        "mvn package", 
        null, 
        new File("C:/Users/Alexander/Projects/Simulator"));
```

Also might need `import java.io.File`

See [docs for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File)) about this overload of exec.

Comment: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "C:\Users\Alexander\Projects\Simulator"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`, why can't I run mvn commands?

Comment: mvn may not be in your Path. To check, in a cmd, run `where mvn` and use the full path. If it says not found, make sure mvn is installed.